# Change 'Var' function of assignin based on user input

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a GUI in MatLab that enables me to take the data it is outputting and move it to the work-space.
I'm currently achieving this with the assigning function but what I would like to happen is have the name of the variable change depending on what the user inputs in a edit box

Here is my current script:

```
function Save_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles, vavargin)

a=str2num(get(handles.VariableA,'String'));
b=str2num(get(handles.VariableB,'String'));    
c=str2num(get(handles.VariableC,'String'));    
d=str2num(get(handles.VariableD,'String'));

regionname=(get(handles.RegionName,'String'));

assignin('base','regionname' ,[a;b;c;d]);
```

Every time the save button is pressed it just calls it region name instead of grabbing the user inputted text.

Does anybody have any ideas? Since I'm fairly new to MatLab, please try to make the explanation as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave off the quotes around `regionname` when you run the assignin command, as follows.  Then it will use the value *inside* the variable `regionname` as the new variable name.

```
assignin('base', regionname ,[a;b;c;d]);
```